# What is the base.Docker file in VSCode's dev containers for?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, dockerfile, vscode-remote

In the *.devcontainer* directories that VSCode uses to build dev images, e.g. the Python 3 one [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-dev-containers/tree/main/containers/python-3/.devcontainer), they always have a *Docker* file and a *base.Docker* file. The *base.Docker* file is not referenced by either the *Docker* file nor the *devcontainer.json* file. What is it for?

Comment: Yes, but I do not understand it :-( Once copied locally into my repository, why would I reconfigure *devcontainer.json* to use *base.Docker* and then edit *base.Docker*, rather than just editing my local copy of the *Docker* file directly?

Answer (score 7):

`base.Dockerfile` is the "recipe" used by Microsoft to generate the image used in `Dockerfile`. In this case, this is `mcr.microsoft.com/vscode/devcontainers/jekyll:0-${VARIANT}`, specied in the `FROM` section at the top of `Dockerfile`.

They state that if you want to customize the image, that you can replace the `FROM` with the contents of `base.Dockerfile`. This is described here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-dev-containers/tree/v0.205.2/containers/jekyll#using-this-definition